# Number Theory stamps

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

There are exactly 33 postage amounts that cannot be made up using two stamps, including 46 cents. What are the values of these two stamps?

Using 
stamp 1 = x
stamp 2 = y and I'm assuming postage amounts range from 1 to 100 cents

My attempt is
ax+by=46 has a negative solution obviously. So either a or b < 0. I cannot get any farther than that.

Comment: maybe my english is bad, but i dont understand the question at all

Comment: If $a,b$ are relatively-prime, then every number larger than $(a-1)(b-1)$ can be written as a non-negative combination of $a,b$. So you know that $(a-1)(b-1)>46$ and ( I assume) $gcd(a,b)=1$

Comment: If there are only two stamps, it would be worth saying this in the question, perhaps instead of "remaining".

Comment: Does the fact that exactly $33$ amounts cannot be made imply that $(x-1)(y-1)=66$?

Comment: @Lost1 For $a,b\in\mathbb N$, let $S(a,b)$ be the set of all $c\in\mathbb N$ such that the equation $ax+by=c$ has **no** solution in integers $x,y\ge0$. Find $a,b$ given that $|S(a,b)|=33$ and $46\in S(a,b)$. At least, that's how I understand the problem.

Comment: @bof $46$ excludes $\{2,67\}$

Comment: @bof Yes exactly 33 is same as $(x-1)(y-1)=66$ since in the range up to last excluded, half the numbers can be made. So only the $\{7,12\}$ remains out of the possibilities, since it is stipulated that $46$ cannot be made.

Comment: @MarkBennet Oh, right, $46$ is even. So you can make it with twos. Thanks!